# How to make this function return pair of combination from array rows in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, combinations

i have the following function

```
import numpy as np

a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l']]
b = np.array(a)

def func01(matrix):
    m,n = np.shape(matrix)
    for jump in range (m-1):
        for row in range (jump):
            for col in range (n):
                print (matrix[row][col],matrix[row+jump][col])

func01(b)
```

this results in:

('a', 'd')
('b', 'e')
('c', 'f')
('a', 'g')
('b', 'h')
('c', 'i')
('d', 'j')
('e', 'k')
('f', 'l')

however i want my result to look like this:

('a', 'd')
('b', 'e')
('c', 'f')
('a', 'g')
('b', 'h')
('c', 'i')
('a', 'j')
('b', 'k')
('c', 'l')
('d', 'g')
('e', 'h')
('f', 'i')
('d', 'j')
('e', 'k')
('f', 'l')
('g', 'j')
('h', 'k')
('i', 'l')

What have I done wrong? Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Make it do like you want? What's the algorithm that you want. Seems like there is a missing 3rd loop somewhere?

Comment: I want the first to the last value of the row 0 to be paired with first to the last value of the row 1 respectively, then row 0 with row 2, row 0 with row 3, after that row 1 with row 2, and so on. Without repeating any pair, (a,d) is the same with (d,a)

Comment: @SurakriKarto See my answer or Christian Sloper's answer below. Should be what you want =)

Comment: yes, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l']]

new_list = []   
for i in range(len(a)): # Loop over the first subgroup
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)): # Loop over the second subgroup
        for k in range(len(a[0])): # Loop through the elements of each subgroup
            new_list.append((a[i][k], a[j][k]))


new_list
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f'),
 ('a', 'g'), ('b', 'h'), ('c', 'i'),
 ('a', 'j'), ('b', 'k'), ('c', 'l'),
 ('d', 'g'), ('e', 'h'), ('f', 'i'),
 ('d', 'j'), ('e', 'k'), ('f', 'l'),
 ('g', 'j'), ('h', 'k'), ('i', 'l')]
```

This could be more concise with a list-comprehension:

```
new_list = [(a[i][k], a[j][k]) for i in range(len(a)) 
            for j in range(i+1, len(a)) 
            for k in range(len(a[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using combinations from itertools and some numpy slicing:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l']]
b = np.array(a)
m,n = b.shape

res = sorted([k for i in range(n) for k in itertools.combinations(b[:,i],2) ])
```

yields:

[('a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'g'),
 ('a', 'j'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('b', 'h'),
 ('b', 'k'),
 ('c', 'f'),
 ('c', 'i'),
 ('c', 'l'),
 ('d', 'g'),
 ('d', 'j'),
 ('e', 'h'),
 ('e', 'k'),
 ('f', 'i'),
 ('f', 'l'),
 ('g', 'j'),
 ('h', 'k'),
 ('i', 'l')]

Comment: Dunno if OP cares: Although these are the same combinations, the ordering is different than OP expected output... Though it's admittedly much cleaner than my posted answer :P

Comment: @StephenCowley ok, good catch. I'll see if i can add some sorting.

Comment: ah, indeed this is clean, only the matter of order is a bit off. thank you!

Comment: @ChristianSloper Still not quite right. OP's goes `[a b c a b c...` I've been playing with your solution a little as well and haven't figured out how to get that order either... _shrug_

Comment: @StephenCowley yeah, i guess it is not obvious how to get the correct order with this. a pity :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the use case that [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) was made for:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l']]

result = [list(zip(*x)) for x in combinations(a, 2)]

# If you want to flatten the result:
flat_result = [item for row in result for item in row]

print(flat_result)
```

result:

```
[[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')],
 [('a', 'g'), ('b', 'h'), ('c', 'i')],
 [('a', 'j'), ('b', 'k'), ('c', 'l')],
 [('d', 'g'), ('e', 'h'), ('f', 'i')],
 [('d', 'j'), ('e', 'k'), ('f', 'l')],
 [('g', 'j'), ('h', 'k'), ('i', 'l')]]
```

flat_result:

```
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f'), ('a', 'g'), ('b', 'h'), ('c', 'i'), ('a', 'j'), ('b', 'k'), ('c', 'l'), ('d', 'g'), ('e', 'h'), ('f', 'i'), ('d', 'j'), ('e', 'k'), ('f', 'l'), ('g', 'j'), ('h', 'k'), ('i', 'l')]
```

Or if you directly want to compute the flat version:

```
result = []
for x in combinations(a, 2):
    result += list(zip(*x))
```

Comment: woah, thank you! I'm still not familiar with all the Python libraries and stuff, hehe

Comment: Yeah, I guessed. That's why I linked the doc to `zip` :-). Python has a rich library which will usually be more efficient and easier to use than anything that you could write (at least as a beginner). So before coding it yourself, browse the docs to see if you can find a built-in functionality which does what you wanna do.